# Can I jump past versions of Rails when upgrading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3.2.6 application that I want to upgrade to 3.2.12. Do I need to go to 3.2.7 then 3.2.8 then 3.2.9 and so on?

Or can I go straight to 3.2.12?

What is recommended as a best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to upgrade the rails version in a sequence. You can upgrade you version directly from 3.2.6 to 3.2.12

Just go to you Gemfile and find the line with ***gem 'rails', '3.2.6'***, replace it with ***gem 'rails', '3.2.12'*** and type `bundle update`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just change rails version in gemfile and run your tests. Most likely you wont have any issues, but make sure you have tested at least basic functions